# Django: edit template inside another template

Tags: django

I am making a CMS using Django, one of the desired features is to give my client ability to edit automatic sent commercial emails by himself (those emails are template files). It's better explained by code. Here is part of my `email_edit.html`:

```
{% block content %}
<form action="">
Subject: <input type="text">
Content: <textarea>{% include "email1.html" %}</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Obviously it doesn't work. `email1.html` itself is a template file, so `include` tag try to render it with context, which is not I wanted. I want to put the content of `email1.html` inside `textarea` to make it editable. How can I do this?

PS: I use Jinja2

Comment: You can store this as a database field, and enable tinymce. This way, your client can edit it

Comment: Why not just leverage Django-CMS?

Comment: @Brandon, thanks I might try it in my next project. But this client needs deeply customized admin I doubt any CMS can fit the job

Comment: @karthikr, thanks but I already did that. My problem is how to render a template stored in db (a string) with context. Basti gave the right answer below.

Comment: Django-CMS is pretty powerful. I highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your user to be able to edit the template, then you should store the template in the database. There are some packages that do this for you, but it's easy enough to do by yourself

```
# in models.py
    class EmailTemplate(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        template = models.TextField()
```

Then when you need to send an email, you can render it like so:

```
# in views.py
from django.template import Template, Context
#in your view     
    email_template = get_object_or_404(EmailTemplate, id = template_id) #You should know how to get this somewhere
    template = Template(email_template.template)
    email_body = template.render(Context({'my_context':'my_context'}))
```

Comment: Exactly what I ask for. Although I figured this out myself an hour ago:)